# Can we release codepush for only specific devices?

Tags: react-native-code-push

My react-native app has the following problem:

There some rare mobile users who have a same problem on production, but I cannot reproduce it on dev env.

So my approach is releasing code-push with debuggable feature for those users only. Assume that I have those deviceIds or any needed target info.

**Can I release code-push for those users only?**

or just one device is ok!